# Cumulative Density Plots with ggplot and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

When we take the following example from ggplot2 docs

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, 0, 3), rnorm(100, 0, 10)),
                 g = gl(2, 100))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step", na.rm = T) + # interchange point and step
  theme_bw()
p
```

We can create a standard cdf plot. Now if we want to play with the plot in `plotly`, I obtain a very confusing image when I use the `step` command. See below. However, when I use the `point` command `plotly` behaves like it should. What is happening with the `step` command? Why can't I recreate the image from using ggplot only?

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: a bug with the current version? even (https://ropensci.github.io/plotly/ggplot2/stat_ecdf.html) does not show up the right graphics

Comment: I was hopeful it was not ......

Comment: have you tried the dev version of plotly devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly") maybe it will help....

Comment: @MLavoie  did you find any solution to this? I'm having the same issue still

Comment: @user63230, I did not pursue this but maybe lukeg did.

Comment: thanks @lukeg did you manage to sort this?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution here https://community.plotly.com/t/bug-with-ggplot2-stat-ecdf-function/1187/3.
You should reorder the dataframe along x.

```
df <- dplyr::arrange(df, x)  
library(ggplot2)  
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) +  
    stat_ecdf(geom = "step", na.rm = T) +  
    theme_bw()  
p  
library(plotly)  
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: i like this answer!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using `ecdf()` function.

```
##  ecdf function to get y and 1-y
rcdf <- function (x) {
  cdf <- ecdf(x)
  y1 <- cdf(x)
  y <- unique(y1)
  # xrcdf <- 1-y  ##  to get reverse cdf
  xrcdf <- y    ##  to get cdf
}

ug <- unique(df$g)
ng <- length(ug)
xll <- min(df$x)
xul <- max(df$x)
adr <- data.frame(myxx=c(), myyy=c(), mygg=c())

lapply(1:ng, function(i){
  ad2r <- subset(df, g==ug[i])
  myx1 <- unique(ad2r$x)
  myxx <- c(xll,myx1,xul)       ##  add lowest value - dummy to assign 100%
  myy1 <- rcdf(ad2r$x)
  # myyy <- c(1.0,myy1,0.0)     ##  add 100%  to get reverse cdf
  myyy <- c(0.0,myy1,1.0)       ##  add 0%  to get cdf
  mygg <- ug[i]
  ad2rf <- data.frame(myxx,myyy,mygg)
  adr <<- rbind(adr,ad2rf)
})

adf <- adr[order(adr$myxx),]

pp <- ggplot(data=adf, 
             aes_(x=adf$myxx, y=100*adf$myyy, col=adf$mygg, group=adf$mygg)) +
        geom_step() +
        labs(title="CDF", y = "Y", x = "X", col=NULL) 

ppp  <-  ggplotly(pp, tooltip=c("x","y"))
ppp
```

This gives the following output:

[CDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmYcl.png)